# How can you use Firefox's JavaScript engine offline?

Tags: javascript, firefox, offline

I have jQuery code which works offline in Safari and Opera, but neither in Firefox 3.1 nor 3.08.

**How can you use Firefox's JavaScript engine in offline debugging?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) and play around with that.

Or you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) which has a JavaScript debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Both Safari and Opera come with JavaScript debuggers.  For Firefox, the weapon of choice is to install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you jQuery isn't running when using a localhost you probably need to make sure that your paths match up.  Different browsers handle relative paths differently when running off the harddrive.  I suggest using static paths.  Also you probably want to checkout FireBug, which is a FireFox plug-in that allows you to inspect the JavaScript.